# How to plot a bifurcation plot that is easily modifed and simply done in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics, wolfram-mathematica

I have many bifurcation plots to do so I want to do something that can be easily modified. The enclosed code is an initial attempt.

```
p1 = Plot[{Sqrt[a], -Sqrt[a]}, {a, -3, 6}];
horiz = Graphics@
  Line[ {{-3, 2}, {6, 2}} ];(*horizontal line at y=2 *)
horiz2 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{-3, -2}, {6, -2}} ];(*horizontal line at y=2 *)
vertm = Graphics@
  Line[ {{-1, -2}, {-1, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=-1 *)
vert0 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{  0, -2}, {0, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=0 *)
vert1 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{  1, -2}, {1, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=1 *)
vert2 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{  2, -2}, {2, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=21 *)
vert3 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{  3, -2}, {3, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=3 *)
vert4 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{  4, -2}, {4, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=4 *)
vert5 = Graphics@
  Line[ {{  5, -2}, {5, 2}} ];(*vertical line at a=5 *)
Show[p1, horiz, horiz2, vertm, vert0, vert1, vert2, vert3, vert4, \
vert5]
```

I want all of the parabola to be red, not blue and gold and in bold so it stands out. It would be nice to label each of the vertical lines below such as a=1. Can you help? Thank you.

Sincerely,
MM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
p1 = Plot[{0, -a}, {a, -4, 4}, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, 
   AxesLabel -> {"a", "y=f_a(y)=dy/dt"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {   {Red, Thickness[0.007]}, {Red, 
      Thickness[0.005]}  }];
vertm3 = Graphics@{Line[{ {-3, -3.5}, {-3, 3.0} }], 
    Text["a = -3", {-3, 3.5}]};
vertm2 = Graphics@{Line[{ {-2, -3.5}, {-2, 3.0} }], 
    Text["a = -2", {-2, 3.5}]};
vertm =  Graphics@{Line[{ {-1, -3.5}, {-1, 3.0} }], 
    Text["a = -1", {-1, 3.5}]};
vert0 =   
  Graphics@{Line[{ {  0, -3.5}, {  0, 3.0} }], 
    Text[  "a = 0", {0, 3.5}]};
vert1 =  Graphics@{Line[{ {   1, -3.5}, {  1, 3.0} }], 
    Text[  "a = 1", {1, 3.5}]};
vert2 =  Graphics@{Line[{ {   2, -3.5}, {  2, 3.0} }], 
    Text[  "a = 2", {2, 3.5}]};
vert3 =  Graphics@{Line [{ {  3, -3.5}, {  3, 3.0} }], 
    Text[  "a = 3", {3, 3.5}]};   
Show[p1, vertm3, vertm2, vertm, vert0, vert1, vert2, vert3, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large,
         Point[{{-3, 0}, {-3, 3}, {-2, 0}, {-2, 2}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 
      1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}, {2, 0}, {2, -2}, {3, 
      0}, {3, -3}}] }]
```

Comment: Why does the `vert0` line end at `{0, 2.5}` rather than `{0, 3.0}` like all the other vert lines?

Comment: It has been corrected... Note change in y axis label.  MM

Answer (score 1):

For a bold red parabola:

```
p1 = Plot[{Sqrt[a], -Sqrt[a]}, {a, -3, 6}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.01]}, {Red, Thickness[0.01]}}];
```

To label the vertical lines:

```
vert1 = Graphics@{Line[{{1, -2}, {1, 2}}], Text["a = 1", {1, 2}]};
vert2 = Graphics@{Line[{{2, -2}, {2, 2}}], Text["a = 2", {2, 2}]};
```

You can use `Table` to simplify generation of the vertical lines.

```
Show[p1, vert1, vert2]
```

[image]

Comment: I want to add multiple equilibrium points to the graph. See below code for 
 1 point. How to add multiple points?  I like your table idea (later when I get this done the hard way)   Show[p1,  vert0, vert1, vert2, vert3, Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{2, -2}}]}]

Comment: Add the coordinates of the points to the list passed to `Point`. E.g to add a point at {1, -2}
`Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{1, -2}, {2, -2}}]}`

Comment: one = {2, -2};
two = {2, 2};Show[p1, vertm3, vertm2, vertm, vert0, vert1, vert2, vert3, 
 Graphics[Point[one], Point[two]]]
Show[p1, vertm3, vertm2, vertm, vert0, vert1, vert2, vert3, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize -> Large, Point[{{2, -2}}]}]

Comment: I am not sure exactly what your question is. If you are asking why `Graphics[Point[one], Point[two]]` does not display any points, that is because `Graphics` takes a list of primitives. Try this `Graphics[{Point[one], Point[two]}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments, I think this is more like what you are trying to do.

```
verticalLines[xmin_, xmax_, step_] := 
 Table[Graphics@{Line[{{x, -2}, {x, 2}}], 
    Text["a = " <> ToString[x], {x, 2.2}], PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{x, -2}], Point[{x, 2}]}, {x, xmin, xmax, step}]

p1 = Plot[{Sqrt[a], -Sqrt[a]}, {a, -3, 6}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Red, Thickness[0.01]}, {Red, Thickness[0.01]}}];

Show[p1, verticalLines[-1, 5, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Rohit,  I need time to study your code. It is not exactly what I wanted but I think the table command may be useful. I am answering my question today. It is the best try so far.  MM